# How can i update Genymotion virtual device version to 2.2.2

Tags: android, genymotion, virtual-device-manager

I'm using Genymotion ver.2.2.0 . Initially i added virtual device Samsung Galaxy Note 3 4.4.2 API 19 - 1080X1920 later i tried to access the virtual device but it thrown an error i.e genymotion version and virtual device version do not match Genymotion ver.2.2.0 and virtual device vr 1.0.0 .

so i checked with some other virtual device i.e google nexus 5 4.4.2 - API 19 - 1080X1920.In that version number shown as 2.2.2. So i though it will match and i installed it .

But still i was facing the same problem. I wasn't getting where this version is mentioned in virtual device. How can i overcome this issue.??

Answer (score 5):

Please check

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#virtual-devices

Its only a paid function. You should delete and create a new one.